# simple tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am very new to tikz and trying to plot some very simple graphs.

I got the following working example, which I do not completely understand yet.

- how would you best connect 1 and 4, 1 and 5, 2 and 4, 2 and 5 so that the arrows still can be identified?
- how can I have the circles the same size adjusted to the biggest one? so far they are as big as needed for the text inside..
- is it possible to have node 4 positioned so that it does not depend on a fixed below-value? Otherwise I can not simply shrink the whole thing by adjusting the distance..

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{blob/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}}
\tikzset{blobg/.style={circle,gray,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,auto,node distance=2cm,on grid,very thick]
    \node (1) [blob] {1};
    \node (2) [blob,right of=1] {2};
    \path (1) -- node (3) [blob,below of=1] {3} (2);
    \node (4) [blob,below=4] {4};
    \node (5) [blobg,right of=4] {512};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [left] {} (3)
    (2) edge node [left] {} (3)
    (3) edge node [left] {} (4)
    (3) edge node [left] {} (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please try to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Following up on Kevin's comment, just extend your code snippet with a document class, the `tikz` package and necessary TikZ libraries, and a `document` environment, so that the whole thing can be copy-pasted and compiled directly.

Comment: To understand the TikZ options, the best source is the [TikZ/PGF Manual](http://www.math.mun.ca/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). Just search the document for the name of the option. Options are linked to their definitions.

Comment: Thank you. Despite auto the options are now clearer. And I managed to have to styles for the blobs for which one simply greys them. So the other questions remain.

Comment: @fjdaklöf: What do you mean by "gray out" the circles? To adjust the size of the circles, add `minimum size=<length>` to the definition of `main node`, where `<length>` can be `15mm`, say.

Comment: @fjdaklöf: Your second question is a bit unclear... What do you mean by connecting 1 and 4,5 exactly? Connecting 1 to 4 and 1 to 5, or 1 to 4 and 4 to 5? About the `<length>` in my previous comment, `3em` seems to be the best, after some experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here two approaches are demonstrated to answer your 3 concerns.

1. Two different methods showing different ways of connecting nodes.
2. The circles can be uniformly adjusted to the biggest one via `\textwidth=\widthof{BiggestOne}` from `calc` of tikzlibrary.
3. The first method (OP) is relative to a node while the second method is adjustable by `column sep` and `row sep`. That is, **no need to use fixed below-value**. Second solution is the matrix node solution. When specifying a matrix of nodes, one can add names to any node by using the `|(<NodeName>)|` notation **before** the node text.

Note: the red circle can be changed into gray.

The first image is the OP. The second image is matrix node method.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

% ---- Mehtod 1

\sffamily\Large\bfseries

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,node distance=2cm,on grid,very thick]
\tikzset{blob/.style={circle, text width=\widthof{512}, text centered, draw}}
\tikzset{blobg/.style={circle, red, draw, text centered}}
    \node (1) [blob] {1};
    \node (2) [blob,right of=1] {2};
    %\path (1) -- node (3) [blob,below of=1] {3} (2);
    \node (3) [blob,below of=1,xshift=1cm] {3}; % modified
    \node (4) [blob,below = 4cm of 1] {4};
    \node (5) [blobg,right of=4,] {512};

  \path%[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node[left] {} (3)
    (2) edge node[left] {} (3)
    (3) edge node[left] {} (4)
        edge node[left] {} (5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm} 

%  --- method 2

\begin{tikzpicture}[boxes/.style={draw, circle, text width=\widthof{5122}, very thick, text centered, text=black},scale=1,->,>=stealth,]
\matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes, nodes=boxes, column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.5cm] 
  {
   |(1)| 1     &               &   |(2)| 2      \\ 
               &   |(3)| 3     &                 \\
   |(4)|4      &               &  \node[red](5){5122}; \\ 
  };  
\draw [very thick, black, ->] (1)--(3);  
\draw [very thick, black, ->] (2)--(3);
\draw [very thick, black, ->] (3)--(4);
\draw [very thick, black, ->] (3)--(5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```